# External Drive appearing as Logical Volume Group, cannot use as Time Machine on Mac

Tags: backup, time-machine

Once upon a time I encrypted my Time Machine and I cannot remember the password I used to encrypt it (yes, very frustrating).

I wiped my Time Machine using Disk Utility, thinking I could just start again, but now it won't let me do anything. I've attached a screenshot of what I see below. I can't seem to use my external hard drive as a Time Machine now. How can I get it back to normal so I can start backing up again? Thanks[image]